# Border-image breaks in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, mozilla, border-image

When trying to apply a "stripy" `border-image` to a text input field it breaks in Mozilla Firefox under certain parameters.

Take a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sxpL9zw1

As you can see the page renders a simple text field with a black stripy border around it. This fiddle actually works just fine in any browser I've tried.

However, things get really weird when I run the exact same markup on my host or on localhost: http://test.tonybogdanov.com/border-image-mozilla-issue/

Here's what I see when I open the URL with the latest Mozilla Firefox (35.0): [image]

As you can see the left and right borders render properly, but the top and bottom ones are somehow "solid" looking. I've also tested this in IE10, Chrome, Opera and Safari on Windows and they all show the border just fine, except Firefox.

Furthermore, when I increase the `border-width` above `9px` the issue disappears, which also happens when I remove the `width` property.

Any ideas what might be causing this or why can't I reproduce it in a jsfiddle?

P.S. I also tried this by drag-and-dropping the HTML file in Firefox (to rule out any host-related issues) and it still fails. Here's a zip to try it yourself: http://test.tonybogdanov.com/border-image-mozilla-issue/files.zip

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to one of the most counter-intuitive bits of CSS.

You can use this tool:  http://border-image.com/  with your image and work out what the correct offsets and border sizes should be. (You can preview the border around the CSS text at the bottom)

Good luck

Comment: Yes, that's a great tool, but the issue really seems to be in Mozilla. Take a look: http://goo.gl/yhDjns Try to change the border size for the top border to a value less than 6 pixels and see what happens :) It's like for anything under 6px Firefox just goes: "oh f**k it, I'm goin' solid."

Comment: All seems to be just fine for left/right borders though.. Btw, the shortener seems to have some issues, here's the full URL: http://border-image.com/#{%22src%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Ftest.tonybogdanov.com%2Fborder-image-mozilla-issue%2Fborder-stripes.png%22%2C%22linkBorder%22%3Afalse%2C%22borderWidth%22%3A%5B12%2C0%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%22imageOffset%22%3A%5B50%2C50%2C50%2C50%5D%2C%22fill%22%3Afalse%2C%22setRepat%22%3Afalse%2C%22repeat%22%3A%5B%22repeat%22%2C%22repeat%22%5D%2C%22scaleFactor%22%3A3%2C%22setRepeat%22%3Atrue}

Comment: Sorry it has been so long - try using round on the edges
[border-image.com](http://border-image.com/#%7B%22src%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FTR%2Fcss3-background%2Fborder.png%22%2C%22linkBorder%22%3Atrue%2C%22borderWidth%22%3A%5B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%22imageOffset%22%3A%5B28%2C27%2C27%2C27%5D%2C%22fill%22%3Atrue%2C%22setRepat%22%3Afalse%2C%22repeat%22%3A%5B%22round%22%2C%22round%22%5D%2C%22scaleFactor%22%3A3%2C%22setRepeat%22%3Atrue%7D)